# Mass-updating a single field in phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

In my `leads` database, I need to mass `update` all records in each `Status` category:

Eg. for records that display status= **'LEAD International'**, I want to change the status for all these records to = **'ASSIGNEDInternational'**.

I have tried using the `Search` method (Search by field, check all, 'change') however this only updates one record at a time.

I tried using this SQL code, but it has an **error**:

```
UPDATE leads SET status = ASSIGNEDInternational, WHERE status = "LEAD International"
```

I'm new to SQL, so I would hugely appreciate your SQL/other suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what exactly is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an extra comma. Remove it like so:

```
UPDATE leads 
SET status = 'ASSIGNED International'
WHERE status = 'LEAD International'
```

Comment: Fantastic -that did the tric.

Answer (score 2):

You were close with your SQL query:

```
UPDATE leads SET status = "ASSIGNEDInternational" WHERE status = "LEAD International"
```